# $\text{rank}(A')-\text{rank}(B')=\text{rank}(A)-\text{rank}(B)$ for free abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I remember a proof I find about uniqueness of decompositions of finitely generated abelian group $A$ using the following lemma:

> Let $p:A'\to A$ an epimorphism from free abelian groups of finite rank. Let $B$ be a subgroup of $A$ and $p^{-1}(B)=B'$. Then $$\text{rank}(A')-\text{rank}(B')=\text{rank}(A)-\text{rank}(B)\quad.$$

Unfortunately I cannot remember the proof, a bit difficult to find it alone, and neither the source.

It will be great if I someone knows a reference.

**Edit**: Ok I think I can prove that lemma, but I failed to see how it helps for uniqueness.

Comment: Probably you mean $\DeclareMathOperator\rk{rank}\;\rk(A')-\rk(B')=\rk(A)-\rk(B)$?

Comment: @Bernard sorry I should ready more carefully before posting my question. Thanks

Comment: Personally, I should often read more carefully my answers before I post them :o)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Prove $A'/B'\simeq A/B$, then tensor with $\mathbf Q$, and use the fact that
$$\DeclareMathOperator\rk{rank}\dim_{\mathbf Q}\bigl(A/B\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q\bigr)=\rk(A)-\rk(B)$$
and similarly for $A'/B'$.

*Note:*

$A/B\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q$ is (isomorphic to) the module of fractions $S^{-1}(A/B)$, with $S$ is the multiplicative subset of non-zero integers. In other words, it is the set of fractions $\dfrac{a+B}s$, where the numerator is a congruence class modulo $B$ and the denominator a non-zero integer. It becomes a $\mathbf Q$-vector space, with addition:
$$\dfrac{a+B}s+\dfrac{a'+B}{s'}=\dfrac{s'a+sa'+B}{ss'}$$
and scalar multiplication:
$$\dfrac pq\dfrac{a+B}s=\dfrac{pa+B}{qs}$$

Comment: I don't what tensor is, the proof I saw was 'elementary'.

Comment: Do you know rings of fractions? I just use that abelian groups are $\mathbf Z$-modules, and we can extend scalar multiplication to $\mathbf Q$ so as to obtain a $\mathbf Q$-vector space.

Comment: Another variant, if you know the structure theorem  for abelian groups: rank$(A)-$ rank$(B)$ is the free rank of $A/B$.

Comment: I've added some explanations but I'm not sure this be very clear.

Comment: your notation between $A/B$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ what does it means ? What do you mean by tensor with $\Bbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: That would be a little long to explain in a comment, but roughly speaking, it is a module (here an abelian group) which represents, in the categorical sense, the functor of bilinear maps from $A/B\times \mathbf Q$ (the ordinary product) to other modules.

Comment: Hum so yes your answer is not elementary (at least beyond my reach). Thanks anyway

Comment: Use  the structure theorem then. The free rank of $A/B$ is the rank of the free abelian group when you decompose a finitelty generated abelian group as the dirext sum of a free abelian group and its torsion subgroup.

Comment: I edited my question, I succeed to prove the lemma but now just need to prove uniqueness using it.